# magento how to send order emails only to the admin (not to customer)

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.4

I want magento to send the order emails only to the admin not to the customer,
because the customer gets an email from another system.

It's possible to send an ordermail to the customer, or to the customer and admin but it seems to be impossible to send the mail only to the admin.

If someone knows how to do it I would be very thankful.

best regards nico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: it's easy. Bad news: you cannot make it in interface, you can only program it.

Overload sending of emails in Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail(), remove sending to customer from there.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot!

I just commentet out this area, and it works.

**/*  $sendTo = array(
            array(
                'email' => $this->getCustomerEmail(),
                'name'  => $customerName
            )
        );
        */**

```
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $sendTo[] = array(
                'email' => $email,
                'name'  => null
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you have a solution now please click the checkmark next to Andrey's post to show other readers that his was the correct answer.